# Take strings as tokens parsing with Parsec

Tags: haskell, parsec

I am using Parsec library to parse a string. The problem I have is that  can't differentiate some tokens because they are words with the same prefix. Simplifying the whole grammar (in my case it's not a regular one), say we have the following:

```
T0 := <empty> | tag0 T1 T0
T1 := tag1 | tag1 T1
```

So I may have strings like "tag0tag1tag1" or like "tag0tag1tag0tag1" etc., basically we have a "tag0" string followed by an arbitrary (not zero) number of "tag1" string, and all this could also be repeated any number of times.

So what I tried was something like:

```
wrongParser :: Parser String
wrongParser = do
    string "tag0"
    many $ string "tag1"
    return "Ok"
```

And tested with

```
ghci> parse wrongParser "Error" "tag0tag1tag1tag0tag1"
Left "Error" (line 1, column 13):
unexpected "0"
expecting "tag1"
```

So what seems to happen here is that the parser read "tag" from "tag0", but it is expecting "tag1" instead (because is still reading `many` of "tag1").

Is there a way to make the parser to take the tag string as a whole so that instead of failing it just assumes that all the many tag1 are already read and stop with no error (maybe another function than `string`)? Or what is the correct way to handle this case?

Comment: No, it is about the *last* `0`, so `...tag1tag0`, and it expects a `1` there...

Comment: See the "line 1, column 13".

Comment: I don't understand your answer. It  expects `tag1` and that's what my question is about. It reads `tag0` instead, because the list of `tag1` ended and there it start a new `tag0`.

Comment: tag0tag1tag1tag0tag1 is not a string that the EBNF grammar you posted can generate. (The question is a sensible enough one with the obvious change, just wanted to give you a chance to say that the correct change is other than the obvious one.)

Comment: @DanielWagner sure, I missed to add  `T0`  in the secons rule. Now I've edited the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common misconception with `Parsec`:

- A parser consumes char by char, by default. (these are called tokens in `Parsec`)
- A failure in `Parsec` is a parser which comsumes less output than expected
- Parsers do not backtrack unless you specify so.

Therefore, your parser works like this

```
string to consume: "tag0tag1tag1tag0tag1"
string consumed: ""

-- *********************
-- Parser: string "tag0"
-- *********************

-- 1st token
string to consume: "ag0tag1tag1tag0tag1"
string consumed: "t"

-- 2nd token
string to consume: "g0tag1tag1tag0tag1"
string consumed: "ta"

-- 3th token
string to consume: "0tag1tag1tag0tag1"
string consumed: "tag"

-- 4th token
string to consume: "tag1tag1tag0tag1"
string consumed: "tag0"

-- ***********************
-- done with string "tag0"
-- ***********************

-- ****************************
-- Parser: many $ string "tag1" 
-- ****************************

-- convince yourself you'll reach this point
string to consume: "tag0tag1"
string consumed: "tag0tag1tag1"

-- keep in mind we are executing (string "tag1")
-- because you put it inside many.
-- So you end up with 
string to consume: "0tag1"
string consumed: "tag0tag1tag1tag"

-- after this, you consume a 0 and fail.
string to consume: "tag1"
string consumed: "tag0tag1tag1tag" 0 ???
```

Probably you want to say, "if you fail reading tag1, just pretend you haven't read it at all". This is called backtracking and you use the `try` combinator to make it happen

```hs
rightParser :: Parser String
rightParser = do
  string "tag0"
  many1 $ try (string "tag1") -- many1 because tag0 must be followed by at least one tag1. try because you want to backtrack tag1 if failure.
  return "Ok"
```

Now if you want to parse the whole string you use `many rightParser`. For the sake of example, let's say you want to return all "tag1"s. Then

```hs
rightParser :: Parser [String]
rightParser = do
  string "tag0"
  many1 $ try (string "tag1") -- same as before, by returns a list of tag1 instead of "Ok"

wholeParser = many rightParser

main = print $ parse wholeParser "Error" "tag0tag1tag1tag0tag1"

> Right [["tag1","tag1"],["tag1"]]
```

Notice, that other libraries (ex: Attoparsec) do always backtrack on failure. This is a design decision made by each library. Also, backtracking can be an expensive operation, so you may want to write your parser differently (example: always parse "tag" and backtrack only on "0" or "1")